# Populating cells within a row more efficiently

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

I'm writing a code that takes the inputs from a user form and populates different worksheets with the data. I store the data from the user form into variables (string or double) but when I populate the worksheets with the information, the macro gets very slow. It takes about 4 seconds to populate each row with my code. I can't figure out myself how to make the code more efficient.

The data is to be pasted in different worksheets (below the code for one worksheet). Within each worksheet, the data is pasted always within the same row (always the first empty line). The columns are fixed and I cannot change them. I have to paste each variable into a particular column, leaving the other columns unchanged.

```
Dim ordSheet As Worksheet
Set ordSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders")
ord_cNorder = 1
ord_cDate = 2
ord_cNarticles = 5
ord_cImpBI = 6
ord_cImpTax = 7
ord_cSellingCh = 8
ord_cShippingBI = 9
ord_cShippingTax = 10
ord_cCustomer = 11
ord_cCountry = 12
ord_cCity = 13
ord_cNotes = 14

With ordSheet

ord_writeLine = ordSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If Me.CBx_Cont = False Then
    .Cells(ord_writeLine, ord_cNorder).Value = Norder
    .Cells(ord_writeLine, ord_cDate).Value = dmyDate
    .Cells(ord_writeLine, ord_cNarticles).Value = Narticles
    .Cells(ord_writeLine, ord_cImpBI).Value = ImpBI
    .Cells(ord_writeLine, ord_cImpTax).Value = ImpTax
    .Cells(ord_writeLine, ord_cSellingCh).Value = SellingCh
    .Cells(ord_writeLine, ord_cShippingBI).Value = ShippingBI
    .Cells(ord_writeLine, ord_cShippingTax).Value = ShippingTax
    .Cells(ord_writeLine, ord_cCustomer).Value = Customer
    .Cells(ord_writeLine, ord_cNotes).Value = Notes
    .Cells(ord_writeLine, ord_cCountry).Value = Country
    .Cells(ord_writeLine, ord_cCity).Value = City
Else
    .Cells(ord_writeLine, ord_cImpBI).Value = ImpBI
    .Cells(ord_writeLine, ord_cImpTax).Value = ImpTax
    .Cells(ord_writeLine, ord_cShippingBI).Value = ShippingBI
    .Cells(ord_writeLine, ord_cShippingTax).Value = ShippingTax
End If
```

**EDIT 04.Jan.21: Improved but still slow**

I changed the code with the suggestions from @bugdrown and @Tim Williams:

- Using `With ordSheet.Rows(ord_writeLine)` instead of `With ordSheet`
- Populating a variant array with the userform data and looping through the array to fill the cells
- Deactivating screen updating

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ordSheet As Worksheet
Set ordSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders")

Dim ord_writeLine As Integer
ord_writeLine = ordSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row+1

Dim ordCols As Variant
Dim ordVals As Variant
Dim ordColsCont As Variant
Dim ordValsCont As Variant
ordCols = Array(1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
ordVals = Array(Norder, dmyDate, Narticles, ImpBI, ImpTax, SellingCh, ShippingBI, ShippingTax, Customer, Country, City, Notes)
ordColsCont = Array(6, 7, 9, 10)
ordValsCont = Array(ImpBI, ImpTax, ShippingBI, ShippingTax)

With ordSheet.Rows(ord_writeLine)
If CBx_Cont = False Then
    For i = 0 To 11 'I set a timer here to test
        .Cells(ordCols(i)).Value = ordVals(i)
    Next i
Else
    For i = 0 To 3
        .Cells(ordColsCont(i)).Value = ordValsCont(i)
    Next i
       Narticles = Narticles + .Cells(5).Value - 1
       .Cells(5).Value = Narticles
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

The total time for this code is now slightly below 3 seconds (25% improvement) but still feels too long.

I put a timer within the if loop and I identified the bottleneck being the first 2 iterations (with aprox. 1.2 seconds each).

The first 2 iterations correspond to Norder (integer) and dmyDate (date).

I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: You could try populating a variant array with the userform data and looping through the array to fill the cells. The userform controls, array elements, and cell range would be in the same order. Should be a lot faster.

Comment: Could you share the complete code from `Sub` to `End Sub`? If I'll be doing it for the *ords*, I might as well do it for the *peds*.

Comment: If instead of `With ordSheet` you use `With ordSheet.Rows(ord_writeLine)` then you can reduce the volume of your code eg. `.Cells(ord_cNorder).Value = Norder`.  Also try turning off calculation/screenupdating for an easy speed-up.